# Adjustable Table with Truncating Data for HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to make a table that has adjustable column sizes. If the column size is adjusted too small, then the data and header inside the table becomes truncated with ellipsis.

I'm using the colResizable library from http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/

```
$("#expand-table").colResizable({
  fixed: false,
  liveDrag: true,
  gripInnerHtml: "<div class='grip2'></div>",
  draggingClass: "dragging"
});
```

My css:

```
.truncate {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle of what I've been trying so far: http://jsfiddle.net/ubm4n2ob/2/

I'm having trouble with a few things:

- The adjustable column size doesn't work inside a div. I plan to have a very long table, so it will be fit inside an overflow div which allows scrolling
- The truncating isn't dynamically working with the table adjustments

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to follow step-by-step the demos on the plugin page. You html code looks a bit different from demos.
Anyway, check this fiddle, it should do what you want. Probably, by setting the same width to both the cell and the inner div, you were causing some border overlap, leading to the impossibility for the plugin to let you resize the column

I tried to remove `fixed: false,` from the plugin's parameters list, I edited your html and added a CSS rule, now it works

```
$("#expand-table").colResizable({
  liveDrag: true,
  gripInnerHtml: "<div class='grip2'></div>",
  draggingClass: "dragging"
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ubm4n2ob/4/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added a small edit to it, so that the table data also truncates: http://jsfiddle.net/ubm4n2ob/5/